# How to hook Android classLoader?

Tags: java, android, hook, classloader

I want to hook the Android classloader, and then I can print the loading order of the classes, like below

```
public class GetClassLoader extends PathClassLoader {

    private static final String TAG = "GetClassLoader";

    public GetClassLoader(String dexPath, ClassLoader parent) {
        super(dexPath, parent);
    }

    public GetClassLoader(String dexPath, String librarySearchPath, ClassLoader parent) {
        super(dexPath, librarySearchPath, parent);
    }

    public Class<?> findClass(String name) throws ClassNotFoundException {
        Log.d(TAG, name);
        return super.findClass(name);
    }
}
```

I use below method, but it not work

```
public class App extends Application {

    private static final String TAG = "App";


    @Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
        super.attachBaseContext(base);
        replaceClassLoader1(new GetClassLoader("DexPathList[[zip file \"/data/app/com.xuliwen.myapplication1-IooSJUvANC7EIX-xaszn1g==/base.apk\"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.xuliwen.myapplication1-IooSJUvANC7EIX-xaszn1g==/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /system/product/lib64]]", super.getClassLoader()));
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Test test = new Test();
        Log.e(TAG, "" + test.getClass().getClassLoader().toString());
    }


    public void replaceClassLoader1(BaseDexClassLoader dexClassLoader) {
        try {
            // android.app.ActivityThread
            Class clzActivityThead = Class.forName("android.app.ActivityThread");
            Method currentActivityThread = clzActivityThead.getMethod("currentActivityThread", new Class[]{});
            currentActivityThread.setAccessible(true);
            Object objActivityThread = currentActivityThread.invoke(null);
            //clzActivityThead.getDeclaredField()
            Field field = clzActivityThead.getDeclaredField("mBoundApplication");
            // AppBindData
            field.setAccessible(true);
            Object data = field.get(objActivityThread);
            Class clzAppBindData = Class.forName("android.app.ActivityThread$AppBindData");
            Field field1 = clzAppBindData.getDeclaredField("info");
            //LoadedApk
            field1.setAccessible(true);
            Object info = field1.get(data);
            Class clzLoadedApk = Class.forName("android.app.LoadedApk");
            Field field2 = clzLoadedApk.getDeclaredField("mClassLoader");
            field2.setAccessible(true);
            field2.set(info, dexClassLoader);
            Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(dexClassLoader);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

test.getClass().getClassLoader() Still PathClassLoader，I want it is GetClassLoader.What can I do to replace the ClassLoader in my application?